# Ios building error with fastlane : No provisioning profile provided

Tags: ios, flutter, fastlane

I have a flutter application. I want to extract the ios application with fastlane and upload it to test flight. I will do testflight operations with auth key. But the application gives the following error while extracting the ipa.

[image]

At the end of the process, the message "ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED" returns.

But I am getting the above error, my fastfile file is like this.

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"

  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "*******",
    issuer_id: "***********",
    key_filepath: "./AuthKey*****.p8",
    duration: 1200, # optional (maximum 1200)
    in_house: false # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
  )

    build_app(
      workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "Runner",
      output_directory: "./ios",
      output_name("****"),
      export_method: "enterprise",
      )

    upload_to_testflight(
      api_key: api_key,
      skip_submission: true,
      ipa: "#{ipa_path}",
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
  )
end
```

I don't understand where is the problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to export ipa with the "enterprise" method. I assume that it should be "app-store".

You can try it with the following:

```
build_app(
  workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
  scheme: "Runner",
  output_directory: "./ios",
  output_name("****"),
  export_method: "app-store",
  )
```